# Git commit author information - Who the heck is Christian S.?

Tags: git

I recently started using git. I tried to follow the instructions of setting my user information, but soemthing seems to go horribly wrong:

```
[test@h] git config --list
user.name=**MY NAME**
user.email=**MY EMAIL**
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=** URL **
branch.master.remote=origin
ranch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

So far, so good. My name & email address seem to be set correctly

```
[test@h] git add somefile
```

I've added a file and now want to commit it:

```
[test@h] git commit -m "test commit"     
[master 280efe4] test commit
Author: Christian S. <strcat@****.com>
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 somefile
```

Suddenly out of nowhere... Christian S.

What have I overlooked? I have no Idea where this name and email address comes from. Is this some default value I forgot to override somewhere?

EDIT: Removed personal information

Comment: http://www.strcat.de/dotfiles/dot.zshexports but, why do *you* have it? (look the GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL variables environment variables, perhaps)

Comment: At least you have Christian's email. Use your favorite mail client to ask him/her? ;)

Comment: @pst that might be the solution

Comment: Is there a simple script that will pull out all environment variables named GIT_* ? Arguably it should be an option (`--env`) within the `git config` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution thanks to pst. I was working on a development server where a system wide .zshrc file is in place.

Apparently the source for the .zshrc file was: http://www.strcat.de/dotfiles/dot.zshexports

And within this file, the Author's name and Email address were hardcoded:

```
if [[ -x `which git` ]]; then
   (( ${+GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL} )) || export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL = "..."
       ...
```

Comment: I still find it staggering that git config --* does not show the "final" configuration

Comment: The reason `git config` does not show it is that environment variables are not considered part of the "configuration".  The fact that `git commit` looks at them is not something `git config` ever considers, in the same way that it does not look at any other possible environment variables (as used by various hook scripts that use `git config` to get settings if the env var is not set, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

What do these give you:

```
git config --system -l
git config --global -l
git config --local -l
```

or in Linux:

```
echo $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
```

or in Windows:

```
echo %GIT_AUTHOR_NAME%
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the config file at `your-repo/.git/config` and check if there is [user] setting there.

The config file in the repository will override the global .gitconfig file.

Comment: [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 url = ***
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master

Comment: I think environment variables override your configuration settings.