# git commit ignoring email in global config and using hostname instead

Tags: git, email, config, commit

I have an issue similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749211/git-commit-author-information-who-the-heck-is-christian-s) where my laptop was using `me<my_emal>` for commits, laptop catastrophically died, got new laptop, reinstalled Wheezy, stuck old drive in new laptop and my commits now use `me<local_hostname>`

My git config has the entries

```
[user]
name = me
email = myemail
```

I have tried the command

```
print_env
```

but `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` are not set.

Of the suggested commands

```
git config --system -l
git config --global -l
git config --local -l
```

only `--global` has `user.name` and `user.email` set and it is correct, `--system` reports `/etc/gitconfig` does not exist and `--local` has no entries for `user*` i.e. no user/email entries in `my-repo/.git/config` only in `~/.gitconfig`.

```
 grep -R GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL / 2>/dev/null
```

returns a bunch of results but does not explicitly set it to `hostname`

As a result this now breaks my building using git-buildpackage as the key to use is `me<my_email>` not `me<hostname>`.

I also spotted [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155410/how-do-i-add-create-a-source-changes-file) on the package building side (which led me to the above post) but that's only for after the commit.

Running out of ideas now.

Comment: Do you commit on the command line? Does `git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT` produce the wrong output as well?

Comment: yes i commit on the command line `git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT` returns the correct `me <myemail>`

Comment: I am using the latest git from wheezy backports 1.9.1-1~bpo70+2

Comment: Okay it appears to working today ... still not sure why.  May try and replicate in a VBox and post back

Answer (score 0):

## Setting null string in local repository is not valid

Hi, my case was your special case. 
(Please be tolerant if this answer was not you intended.)

#### Prerequisite

`(OS X 10.10.5, git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)/git version 2.7.0 from Homebrew)`

#### Settings

The local repository had only null string like bellow!
In this case,
GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT set to `` `id -F`<`logname`@`hostname`> ``
(I thought old git version 1.9 or so was effective with this configuration though)

localrepo/.config

```
[user]
name = ""
email = ""
```

$HOME/.config

```
[user]
name = me
email = myemail
```

#### Intention

I didn't want to log user.email. and user.name.

Maybe what you said

> no entries for user* i.e. no user/email entries in my-repo/.git/config only in ~/.gitconfig

is actually like above?

#### Solution

localrepo/.config

```
[user]
name = " "
email = " "
```

A space was effective to achieve my intention.